# Converting carray to initializer_list for istream

Tags: c++, arrays, initializer-list, istream

I need to read array elements from the stream, and I have `std::initializer_list<double>` as constructor. I couldn't find anything related to this. Is it possible to read `carray` elements from input stream? I have to variables in `Vector` class I defined:
`double* data` and `size_t rows_`

My code is as following;

**Constructor**

```cpp
Vector::Vector(std::initializer_list<double> il) : data(nullptr){`

    rows_ = l.size();
    data = new double[rows_];
    std::copy(il.begin(), il.end(), data); 
}
```

**friend function for istream**

```cpp
std::istream& operator >>(std::istream &inputStream, Vector& m) {

    
    double *buff = new double[m.rows_];
    
    for (size_t i=0; i !=m.rows_; ++i)
        is >> buff[i];
    
    // buff (array) --> initializer_list as "init_list"
    m = Vector(init_list);
    delete []buff;
    return inputStream; 
}
```

Comment: I'm lazy. I'd have a `private` function that replaces the existing buffer in `m` with `buff`.

Comment: `std::initializer_list` is not well suited for this purpose. Consider giving `Vector` a constructor template which takes two iterators instead.

Comment: Why not istream read directly to vector m? is >> m[i]. instead of is >> buff >> list >> m.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, especially @ytlu. I'm a beginner in c++, so I'm just trying to adapt the codes I've seen to my problems. I didn't know `is >> m[i];` would work, all instances I've seen is on `char` variables, so I thought in that way.

Comment: @Anil Bora Yayak Cheers.

Comment: @ytlu I would like to mark your comment as the best answer if you write it to the answer part.

Comment: @Anil Bora Yayak No. Not necessary. I am glad to be helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `std::initializer_list<T>` is a rather special beast. It essentially exposes a sequence of `T` values somehow sitting on the internal stack in a form which can be iterated. The only way to create such an entity is to actually have the values directly sitting in an `std::initializer_list<T>`. There is no way to create an `std::initializer_list<T>` with a variable number of elements.

My recommendation would be to equip your `Vector` class with a constructor taking iterators, e.g.:

```
class Vector
{   
    std::unique_ptr<double[]> buff = 0;
    int                       size = 0;
    int                       capacity = 0;
public:
    template <typename InIt>
    Vector(InIt begin, InIt end) {
        for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
            if (size == capacity) {
                capacity = std::max(16, 2 * capacity);
                std::unique_ptr<double[]> tmp(new double[capacity]);
                std::copy(buff.get(), buff.get() + size, tmp.get());
                buff = std::move(tmp);
            }   
            buff[size++] = *it;
        }   
    }   
    // ...
};
```

The dance with the `capacity` is to avoid bad complexity of the operation in case the sequence is large: increasing the array one element at a time (or any fixed number `n`) would have quadratic complexity. The approach of increasing the array by a constant factor results in linear complexity. You could, in theory, determine the length of the sequence (`std::distance(begin, end)`) but for input iterator that could *consume* the sequence.

Once that constructor is in place you can read the input using stream iterators like this:

```
    Vector(std::istream& in)
        : Vector(std::istream_iterator<double>(std::cin),
                 std::istream_iterator<double>()) {
    }
```